# Why in python a 2nd object after construction has 1st object's data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, object, memory-management

I have written a python3 classifier class which looks as follows:

```
class BayesPredictor:
    word_counts = {}

    def train(X, y):
        ... populates word_counts dictionary with data ...
```

When I construct the `BayesPredictor` object for the first time, the `word_counts` dictionary is empty:

```
predictor = BayesPredictor()
print(predictor.word_counts) # prints {}
```

However, when I train the first object and then construct another object again:

```
predictor.train(X, y) # here X and y are my training data

predictor2 = BayesPredictor()
print(predictor2.word_counts) # prints { 'goodies': 1, 'mat': 1, 'uve': 1, ... }
```

I see that the second object already has entries in the `word_counts` dictionary even before the training phase.

**Why does this happen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`word_counts` is a class attribute, shared by all instance of `BayesPredictor`. If you want a separate `dict` for each instance, you need to create a new empty `dict` for each instance, ideally in `__init__`:

```
class BayesPredictor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.word_counts = {}

    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because word_counts is a class variable. Meaning that all instance of your class will share this variable.

What you need is an instance variable.

Your code could be modified like this:

```
class BayesPredictor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.word_counts = {}

    def train(X, y):
        ... populates word_counts dictionary with data ...
```